# Mysql Queries parameters and passing values

Tags: java, mysql

I have a general question regarding mysql queries and java. Can you take a value that has been entered into a textbox by a user then assign that to a `String`, then in a whole separate class capture that `String` to fulfill the parameter in a mysql query. The mysql query would run and if the parameter is equal to the data in the table it will return a message of successful login etc. So I am asking for a yes or no style answer on this...any extra input would be helpful but not required. I know you can pass values from one class to another but in this instance I do wonder if it is possible in the running of a mysql query.

Comment: Yes of course, but your question is very vage.

Comment: I have two classes. Class 'A' is the connection to the mysql DB and also will hold the query. Class 'B' is a form that asks the user for login and password. I want to pass the values that are entered into the textbox and pass them back to Class 'A' to fulfill the parameters in a select query. I have the code written and I have done some print statements to see if the values are being passed and they are but they don't seem to be allowing the query to run and to what it is supposed to do. I would be willing to post the code but I am not sure how I can do that if it is possible.

Comment: How clear should it be. I like these sites but when I get replies like this it is very frustrating. If it is a language barrier then say so. My question is framed quite well and if I could post my code it would make it more clear. Clarity is not what is missing here.

Comment: A question in good shape should contain exactly what you try to achieve, what you have tried so far (including code) and where exactly you are stuck. A question that can be answered with yes or no tends to be too broad. And think about it: Your question could be answered with a million different code segments. And a question on a Q&A site like this should have 1 definitve answer to be helpful not only for you but for future visitors.

Comment: In your comment to the answer you stated you have different code already written. please add such code to future questions to get you to your goal directly. And if you have questions about asking properly then visit http://meta.stackoverflow.com. There you'll find a great source of info about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's possible. How would we implement applications using a database if it weren't:

In GUI:

```
String login = loginField.getText();
boolean exists = userDao.checkUserExistence(login);

...
```

In UserDAO:

```
public boolean checkUserExistence(String login) {
    String sql = "select u.id from user u where u.login = ?";
    PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setString(1, login);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    return rs.next();
}
```

Note that the above is only pseudo-code. It doesn't handle exceptions and doesn't close resources properly. It's just to give you an idea.

[Learn about prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the answer. I have some code written, just not in this way. I like the approach. I figured there was a way, just was going about it a little to direct and not calling things properly.